# WHERE condition is not working with aggregate function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select data from table using the below query.

My table:
[image]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalcount,
       SUM(English) as EnglishTotal,
       SUM(Tamil) as TamilTotal,
       SUM(Maths) as MathsTotal,
       SUM(EVS) as EVSTotal,
       SUM(Science) as ScienceTotal 
  from StudentMarks 
 where Class='"+Classs+"' and Section='"+Section+"' and ExamType='"+Exam+"';
```

If I check above query with `ResultSet` like below,

```
if(!rscount.isBeforeFirst()){   
    System.out.println("Cominggggg iffff");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Cominggggg elsee");
}
```

The condition always goes to else part even `WHERE` condition is not satisfied.

Note: If I change my query to `SELECT * from StudentMarks where Class='"+Classs+"' and Section='"+Section+"' and ExamType='"+Exam+"';` then it's working fine.

Could someone guide me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use group by clause after where clause .i.e GROUP BY (Sno)

Comment: See normalisation. An RDBMS table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalcount,SUM(English) as EnglishTotal,
SUM(Tamil) as TamilTotal,SUM(Maths) as MathsTotal,
SUM(EVS) as EVSTotal,SUM(Science) as ScienceTotal 
from StudentMarks where Class='"+Classs+"' 
and Section='"+Section+"' and ExamType='"+Exam+"' GROUP BY Section;
```

I have added group by clause after where condition.